# Не работает клик при входе на страницу

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Сделал вот такое:

```
 <button id="block1"></button> 
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('/shop/invoices', function (data) {  
    $('#block1').html( $('.col_inv_id', data).html() ) 
});
}); 
</script> 
 <script type='text/javascript'>
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#block1 a').trigger('click');
}, 8000);

$('#block1 a').click(function() {console.log('click')})
</script>
```

По идеи, при входе на страницу должен был произойти клик по кнопке и переход на нужную страницу.
Кусок, который подгружается:

```
 <button id="block1"><a href="/shop/order/UqSUWOw423YzfeP9yt0DAU5hg9ZnvUdNI6MVPsko" title="Просмотр заказа">00018</a><small><a href="javascript://" onclick="return invoiceJournal('18')">журнал</a></small></button>
```

а также вторая ссылка скрыта

```
 <style>#block small a {pointer-events: none;cursor: default;display:none}</style>
```

При входе на страницу через 8сек. должен быть клик и переход на нужную страницу, но его нет.Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что после загрузки страницы отправляется ajax запрос, и паралельно в это же время Вы вешаете обработчик на тег `a` которого в принципе нет так как ajax запрос еще не выполнился. В результате `$(#block1 a)` вернёт `null`. Ниже код со вставленной ссылкой `a` как буд-то ajax завершился и клик работает. Второй код в качестве решения под Вашу задачу, если работать не будет проверяйте что возвращает `get` запрос. Ну и `.col_inv_id` этот класс. так как Вы его не указали.

**UPD**. Добавлен редирект на сайт! средствами js и в первом и во втором случае.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <button id="block1"><a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com">Ссылка</a></button> 
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('/shop/invoices', function (data) {  
    $('#block1').html( $('.col_inv_id', data).html() ) 
});
}); 
</script> 
 <script type='text/javascript'>
setTimeout(function(){
  var link = $('#block1 a').attr('href');
  window.location.replace(link);
}, 8000);

</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <button id="block1">
        
    </button> 
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('/shop/invoices', function (data) {  
        $('#block1').html( $('.col_inv_id', data).html() );
        setTimeout(function(){
          var link = $('#block1 a').attr('href');
          window.location.replace(link);
        }, 8000);
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: что так, что так - не работает

Comment: @Garmi что значит что так что так? нажмите "выполнить код" первом варианте и через 8 секунд появится слово клик в консоле. Если Вам нужен редирект на страницу указанную в ссылке, то `trigger('click')` или `click()` не копирует поведение a!! У Вас и не будет происходить редирект. для этого необходимо использовать редирект js. Сейчас исправлю ответ и покажу пример

Comment: @Garmi поправил ответ. Через 8 секунд происходит редирект на стек, во втором случает будет редирект на ссылку которую добавляете в html

Comment: @Garmi при условии что всё правильно делаете

Comment: Ух ты, заработало)Спасибо.Остался последний вопрос:  этот скрипт стоит на каждой странице, как он работает: при входе на страницу пользователя перебрасывает куда надо, там уже (там этого скрипта нету) в localstorage и cookie добавляется нужная запись, и потом с помощью history.back() пользователя возвращает туда, где он был.Но как раз тут и проблемка еще одна: все начинается по новому, и так продолжается вечно.Как можно сделать, что если, например, пользователь зашел на /shop/ "процедура провелась", и его вернуло на страницу, но так, чтобы он мог просматривать ее по нормальному?

Comment: Ну и при переходе на другую, так же

Comment: @Garmi ну если сильно не углубляться в Вашу логику, то раз Вы записываете значение в localstorage и cookie то когда возвращаете назад делайте проверку на есть ли значение в localstorage? если да, то не выводите setTimeout иначе оставляете как есть поведение с редиректом.

Comment: Точно.. спасибо

Comment: @Garmi пожалуйста :)

Comment: Хотя..если у пользователей не будет того, что надо, то по факту редиректа и проверки не будет и это не будет работать.. есть ли другой способ, например, сделать чтобы редирект был раз в 3 часа, и после этого пользователь имел 3 часа "свободы", после того, как они закончатся - ещё раз проверка, и потом "свобода" на 3 часа и т.д ( примерно как и работает CloudFlare)?

Comment: @Garmi это уже сложный и другой вопрос для обсуждения. Но у кук есть время жизни! так записывайте куки сервером или чем Вы там делаете, на 3 часа и после проверяйте время истекло или нет. Ну или если У вас для авторизованного пользователя делаются все эти действия, то тот же трюк можно провернуть с временем сессии пользователя на сайте после авторизации. На данный момент не подскажу как верно будет в вашем случае.

Comment: Дмитрий, вы бы не подсказали, как сделать подгрузку div id="block212zak" по той ссылке (что у вашем ответе, на которую и происходит переадресация) и вывод ее на странице, например, в <div id=podg1>BLOCK</div>?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

button.click(() => {
  banner.addClass("alt");
  console.log('Был клик по кнопке');
});

setTimeout(() => button.trigger("click"), 2000);
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button>Change color</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Ответ вообще не по теме.

Comment: Сделайте пример нормальный и будет по теме. Я вам дал простой пример автоклика, ни кто разбираться в get запросе не будет, ищите что там у вас не работает. И уберите onclick из разметки это древний способ из каменного века, давайте ещё стили засунем в html))

Comment: Да и как не по теме, вот название вашеё темы "Не работает клик при входе на страницу", разве мой ответ не тот?